# Issue using log rotating with Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have this on my log4j.properties, but the log file is not rotating as expected. Not sure if I'm missing something.

```
# Disable the rootlogger
log4j.rootLogger=

#JBaseService logger
log4j.category.com.company.basesvc.common.server.log.SafeLog=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.company.basesvc.javascript.core.JavascriptLog=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.snmp4j.log.Log=error, stdout, fileout
#log4j.category.com.company.cwmp=off, stdout, fileout

# Test log
log4j.category.com.company.unittest.Log=aud0, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.company.mockdevice.Log=debug, stdout, fileout

#3rd party loggers
log4j.category.javax.net.ssl=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.javax.jms=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.hibernate=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.com.mchange=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.httpclient=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.apache=error, stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.springframework=error,stdout, fileout
log4j.category.org.mongodb.driver=warn,stdout, fileout

# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] <%t> %m%n
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] %C line: %L <%t> %m%n

# File output...
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.fileout.File=/var/log/company/cls.log
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] <%t> %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

The file cls.log is created properly under /var/log/company.
But when it reaches 100KB it's not creating a new file and rotating as expected.

Ok, I noticed that every time I restart the server, if the original file is bigger than the what I defined on the log4j.properties, is rotates the file. But only when I restart the server. Someone knows why it's happening?

Is there any attribute I need to add to make it work properly? Or Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Thanks!